# Suppose $f'$ exists on $\mathbb{R}$. If $f(0) = 1$ and $|f'(x)| \leq 1$, prove that $|f(x)| \leq |x| + 1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f'$ exists on $\mathbb{R}$. If $f(0) = 1$ and $|f'(x)| \leq 1$, prove that $|f(x)| \leq |x| + 1$

I see that since the derivative is bounded that $f$ satisfies a lipschitz condition. I know I need to use this fact somewhere. Help!

Comment: Try the MVT.   $\,\,\,\,$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that by the mean value theorem we have $$f(x) - f(0) = f'(\xi)x.$$ This implies that $$|f(x)| \le |f(x) - f(0)| + |f(0)| \le |f'(\xi)||x| + 1\le |x| + 1.$$

Comment: Wow, that simple. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad you like my solution! :)